# Java: Racing against the garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, race-condition

I've implemented an `Object` cache like so:

```
// Dictionary with weak keys & values
private Map<Object, WeakReference<Object>> cache = new WeakHashMap<>();

private Object checkCache(Object obj) {

    // If it's in the cache, returned the cached copy.
    if (cache.containsKey(obj)) return cache.get(obj).get();

    // Store it in, and return it.
    cache.put(obj, new WeakReference<>(obj));
    return obj;
}
```

Picture the following race-condition scenario:

1. `cache.containsKey(obj)` returns `true`
2. The **garbage collector** kicks in and reaps the object in the cache.
3. `null` is returned.

The questions are:

- Can this really happen? AFAIK the GC can kick in at *any* time.
- Can Java GC be disabled for a single method call? `synchronized` doesn't seem to prevent GC.
- Are there any work-arounds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're misusing `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: @SLaks Could you please elaborate why?

Comment: In this case, you have both a weak key and a weak value.

Comment: Here', using `containsKey` is just a way to slow it down. No matter what you're trying to achieve, using `get` and testing for `null` is always better (unless you have to deal with the `null` key, which is nearly always better to avoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this really happen?

Yes.

> Can Java GC be disabled for a single method call?

No.

> Are there any work-arounds?

Yes: you attempt to retrieve the object from the cache (thereby establishing a strong reference if it's still in the cache), and add to the cache if that reference is `null`:

```
WeakReference<Object> ref = cache.get(obj);
Object cached = (ref != null) ? ref.get() : null;
if (cached != null) {
    return cached;
}
else {
    cache.put(obj, new WeakReference(obj));
    return obj;
}
```

**You still need to synchronize the method**, otherwise you could have two threads updating the cache at the same time (and the resulting [update race](http://blog.kdgregory.com/2013/10/immutability-and-thread-safety-part-2.html) would be the [least of your worries](http://blog.kdgregory.com/2012/03/synchronizing-put-is-not-sufficient.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Are the WeakHashMap and WeakReference required? You can use normal HashMap with normal keys then use a timer thread that will clear the old values in the HashMap. GC is quite unpredictable, so unless you don't mind having null values in your map, I suggest using normal ones.

For concurrency, look in Java 7 [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface. It is way better than syncronized methods in terms of control and performance. Check this block about [Java Lock Example and Concurrency Lock vs synchronized](http://www.journaldev.com/2377/java-lock-example-and-concurrency-lock-vs-synchronized?PageSpeed=noscript).